# Self-replicating Buttons Without Recursion

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I want to make a button that when clicked appends a new button to the body element, I want this button to be a copy of the original button such that when it is clicked it also appends a new button to the body element that has the same functionality as the previous two buttons. This is nonsensical I am aware, this is purely a learning exercise :).

What I have currently is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning Things :3</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">CLICK ME</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("did something");
    });
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly except the function is not the function I want, I want to put:

`btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction());`

But this gives me an error "too much recursion", I assume that this is because when it tries to append the new button it runs through the function once to check that there's no errors in the function but that causes an infinite loop, what's an elegant solution to this?

Edit: fix typo

Comment: The second parameter to `addEventListener` should be a function, but instead of passing `myFunction` as that parameter you're *calling* `myFunction()` and passing its *result*. If `myFunction` calls itself in this way it would definitely cause the recursion error you're seeing. Did you mean to pass the function, rather than its result, as the second parameter, i.e. `btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction)`?

Comment: As i understand `CLICK ME` button creates new buttons with `click` event that display the alert message.

Answer (score 3):

```
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction)
```

is what you want.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction())
```

calls `myFunction` before `addEventListener`, so it's an infinite loop.

If you want to create a variable UI in HTML, I recommend using a web framework like [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/). [Here's the same example I made using it](https://svelte.dev/repl/6613a5551d79452f814385494294ecf4?version=3.16.0).

Answer (score 1):

`someFunction()` calls the function right there, but you just need to pass it to `addEventListener()` as `someFunction`:

```js
let number=1;
function someFunction(){
  let btn=document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerText=number++;
  btn.addEventListener("click",someFunction);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
someFunction();
```